# error in counting code lines of a function after parsing a .py file using Python’s ast library

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

the line count after ast processing is incomplete, with only the first two being complete and everything after ‘draw questions’ being incomplete.
lineCount.py is here

```
import ast


def get_function_info(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        tree = ast.parse(f.read())
        functions = [node for node in tree.body if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef)]
        function_info = []
        for function in functions:
            function_name = function.name
            function_line_count = function.body[-1].lineno - function.body[0].lineno + 1
            function_info.append((function_name, function_line_count))
        print(len(functions))
        print(function_info)
        return len(functions), function_info


get_function_info('mathQuiz.py')
```

the mathQuiz.py is the file to be counted, which is shown here

```
import turtle
import random
import math


def draw_square():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(25)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(25)
    turtle.left(90)


def generate_question():
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    questions = set()  
    while len(questions) < 5 * 3:
        operator = random.choice(operators)  
        if operator == "+":
            a = random.randint(0, 99)  
            b = random.randint(0, 99 - a)  
            result = a + b  
        elif operator == "-":
            a = random.randint(1, 99)  
            b = random.randint(1, a)  
            result = a - b  
        elif operator == "*":
            a = random.randint(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(99)))  
            b = random.randint(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(99)))
            result = a * b
        else:
            result = random.randint(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(99)))  
            b = random.randint(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(result)))
            a = result * b
        question = f'{a} {operator} {b} = '  
        if question not in questions:  
            questions.add(f'{question}{result}')
    return questions


def draw_question(questions):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-200, 200)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i, question in enumerate(questions):
        turtle.write(question, font=('Arial', 16, 'normal'))  
        draw_square()

        if i % 3 == 2:  
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(-200, turtle.ycor() - 50)
            turtle.pendown()
        else:  
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + 75, turtle.ycor())
            turtle.pendown()


def draw_answer(questions):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-200, -100)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i, question in enumerate(questions):
        turtle.write(question, font=('Arial', 16, 'normal'))  
        
        draw_square()
        
        if i % 3 == 2:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(-200, turtle.ycor() - 50)
            turtle.pendown()
        else:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + 75, turtle.ycor())
            turtle.pendown()


def put_answer(answers):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-100, -100)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i, answer in enumerate(answers):
        turtle.write(answer, font=('Arial', 16, 'normal'))  
        
        if i % 3 == 2:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(-100, turtle.ycor() - 50)
            turtle.pendown()
        else:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + 175, turtle.ycor())
            turtle.pendown()



turtle.hideturtle()  
turtle.speed(0)  

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-250, 250)
turtle.write("Quiz", font=("Arial", 24, "normal"))
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(100)


questions = generate_question()
questions_without_answer = [question.split('=')[0] + ' = ' for question in questions]  
draw_question(questions_without_answer)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-250, -50)
turtle.write("Answer", font=("Arial", 24, "normal"))
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(100)

draw_answer(questions_without_answer)

answers = [question.split('=')[1] for question in questions]
put_answer(answers)

turtle.done()
```

I don’t understand what’s wrong with this code, I hope to get the correct line processing result.

Comment: Are you trying to find the number of lines of code per function?

Comment: yes, I want to do so

Comment: You need a recursive approach to handle the bodies of objects such as ast.While which themselves have *body* attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_function_info` function seemed to work for function bodies that started and ended with unindented lines. Here's an alternative solution that uses the `inspect` module. Note that the argument to the `get_function_info` is just the name of the module and not the full file name.

```py
import inspect
import importlib


def get_function_info(module_name):
    """Parse a file and return the number of lines of code in each function."""
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
    function_info = []
    for name, value in functions:
        function_line_count = len(inspect.getsourcelines(value)[0]) - 1
        function_info.append((name, function_line_count))
    return len(functions), function_info


num, info = get_function_info("mathQuiz")
print(num)
print(info)
```

Outputs:

```
5
[('draw_answer', 16), ('draw_question', 15), ('draw_square', 11), ('generate_question', 24), ('put_answer', 14)]
```

You'll also want to wrap your unindented code in the `mathQuiz` module in a `main` function and call it like below to avoid executing your program when you import the module.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thank you,I will try a bit later

Comment: It really works, and the result is amazing, thank you. I'm a little doubt about--what's `function[1]` in `for function in functions:`mean

Comment: @XiaoLin take a look at [inspect.getmembers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers). It returns a list of tuples with name as the first item and the member info as the second item. It might be more clear to unpack the name and value in the for loop. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: thank you very much, after 
`for function in functions:
      print(function)
`
I've understood what's `function[1]` mean, it's each function's address